# How can I use pebble SDK on my windows PC in Xamarin environment

Tags: android, xamarin, pebble-watch

I want to develop some android apps that can communicate with my pebble. All I have : 
Windows 8 PC / Android phone: Nexus 5 / Xamarin Studio. 
I tried to import the pebble Kit JAR file. But failed. How can I use it based on my develop environment? 
PS.I have asked many people on here: 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/58837#Comment_58837 ; 
http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/13423/how-can-i-use-pebble-sdk-on-xamarin#latest . 
Any assistance or materials would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pebble development is not supported on Windows.

The [official recommendation for Windows users](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/getting-started/windows/) is to use the [online CloudPebble IDE](https://cloudpebble.net/).

Before Pebble embraced CloudPebble the recommendation was to install an Ubuntu VM and work there.

Edit: It looks like Xamarin Studio also runs on OSX, which [*is* a supported development platform for Pebble](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/getting-started/macosx/). You may have better luck there.